# Async Task data being inserted multiple times. Android

Tags: android

I am trying to insert messages by the user to the xml file database.

My client is on android and server on php.Php is responsible for inserting data in xml.

User writes his message in the textbox and press submit the text is inserted in the listview one time but in the database multiple times.

I've tried directly inserting the values in the xml file through `php` by passing the same arguments which I am sending from the android app and it works fine.It inserts the value only one time.

Here's the code for the submit button which inserts in listview as well as call `asynctask` to insert in database:

```
final Button Submit= (Button) findViewById(R.id.SubmitButton);
            Submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {

                        String     data=chatbox.getText().toString();

                        HashMap<String,String> hashMap=new HashMap<String,String>();    
                        hashMap.put("You",chatbox.getText().toString());    //insert username(You) value in chatbox to hashmap

                        hashMap.put(HandleJSON.Key_username, "You");
                        hashMap.put(HandleJSON.Key_messageText, data);
                        hashMap.put(HandleJSON.Key_messageDate, UserAdminChatActivity.LastShowingChatDate);

                        HandleJSON.newObject=false;
                        adapter.hashmap.add(adapter.hashmap.size(), hashMap);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        new InsertAdminChat().execute();

         }});
```

Here's the `asynctask` class which calls the `httprequest` function to insert data in the database.

```
     public class InsertAdminChat extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... void1) {
                sendHttpRequest("set", "admin", "You" ,chatbox.getText().toString(),clientEmail,"");                    
                return null;
            }
     }
```

This is the httpRequest function:

```
private String sendHttpRequest(String action,String callFrom,String userName,String chatText,String email,String dateChat)
 {
        httpRequest=new HttpRequest(action,callFrom,userName,chatText,email,dateChat);  
        String data=httpRequest.ExecuteRequest();
        Log.i("mojiiiiii",data);
        httpRequest.ExecuteRequest();
        return data;
 }
```

and this is my `HTTPREQUEST` class which is called by httprequest function and is used to insert the data in the database.

```
public class HttpRequest {

private final String action;
private final String callFrom;
private final String userName;
private final String chatText;
private final String email;
private final String dateChat;

private HttpClient httpclient;
private HttpGet httpget;
private HttpResponse response ;
private HttpEntity entity;

public HttpRequest(String action,String callFrom,String userName,String chatText,String email,String dateChat)
{


    this.action=action;
    this.callFrom=callFrom;
    this.chatText=chatText;
    this.email=email;
    this.userName=userName; 
    this.dateChat=dateChat;

        httpclient= new DefaultHttpClient();
        httpget = new HttpGet("http://10.116.25.189/php/Chat/xmlManipulator.php?" +
                                                        "action="+this.action+
                                                        "&username="+this.userName+
                                                        "&chatText="+this.chatText+
                                                        "&email="+this.email+
                                                        "&callfrom="+this.callFrom+
                                                        "&dateChatToRetrieve="+URLEncoder.encode(this.dateChat));   //test purposes k liye muazzam
}

public String ExecuteRequest()
{
    try {
    response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
    entity=response.getEntity();

    if(entity!=null)
    {
              InputStream inputStream=entity.getContent();
              String result= convertStreamToString(inputStream);
              Log.i("finalAnswer",result);
              return result;
    }
}
catch (ClientProtocolException e) 
{

    Log.e("errorhai",e.getMessage());
}
catch (IOException e) 
{
    Log.e("errorhai",e.getMessage());
}
    return "";
}

private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line = null;
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");

        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
 }     



}
```

Comment: in the http request function why do you call execute request 2 times?

Comment: oh thats very silly :) thnx for pointing out.